# Are there any reporting tools for MVC4?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

For the ASP .NET there is crystal reports and always was. But since MVC does not come with toolbox with crystal reports, what are the reporting tool that people typically use with MVC4?

i have two scenarios

1. if i use HTML has the client what are reporting tools that developers use?
2. if the client has JQUERY UI, what are reporting tools developers use?

Comment: Not very clear on "if the client has jquery gui", GUI has to be in html or razor or aspx in case of mvc. Jquery could be used within these pages as java script librarry

Comment: @Yogi i have corrected it to Jquery UI  : )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Telerik Reporting (http://www.telerik.com/products/reporting.aspx) is a good comprehensive option. It provides viewers of many types of applications including ASP.Net MVC.

You can also use SQL Server reporting service (SSRS) in you MVC application using MvcReportViewer available at github (https://github.com/ilich/MvcReportViewer)

We have infact used crystal reports in on of our project, for the power and flexibility it gives and we were allowed to use it. [This](http://www.fdfriends.com/crystal-reporting-with-mvc4-mvc5-razor-view-step-by-step-tutorial/) link can help you if you wish to do so.

Having said that, with the evolution of web technologies, you can represent you data in a variety of visuals using HTML5, jquery plugins, CSSes and many other tools out there, and export them, with having little need of reporting component.